# Get out of a "for loop" in Java

Tags: java

I would like to get out from a "for loop" when an event happened. For instance there is a part of my code :

```
for (ScanResult scanResult : listeScan) {
    if(sampleposition[position]==0){ 
        change=true;
        while(i < position && change==true){ 
            if(macAdress[i].equals(scanResult.BSSID)){ 
                change = false;
            }
            i++;
        }
        i=0;
        if(change == true && scanResult.level >= -80){ 
            valueSSID[position] = scanResult.level;
            macAdress[position] = scanResult.BSSID;
            sSID[position] = scanResult.SSID;
            if(valueSSID[position]!=0){sampleposition[position]++;}
          //exit here
        }
    }
    else{
        if(macAdress[position].equals(scanResult.BSSID) && sampleposition[position]<=totalsample){addlevel=scanResult.level;} else {addlevel=0;}
        valueSSID[position] = valueSSID[position] + addlevel;
            if(addlevel!=0){sampleposition[position]++;}
          //exit here

        }
    }
}
```

Actually, I would like to stop the loop where there are the comments "exit here".

Please, can you tell me how can I proceed? Sorry for my english...

Comment: Note that the language used for Android progamming is Java. You are not looking for an Android functionality but a Java functionality.

Comment: change ``//exit`` here to ``break;``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
break;
```

This exits out of the for loop entirely.

```
continue;
```

This goes on to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: another possibility is to use `return` if the rest of the method logic is not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the `break` keyword, this will end the loop immediately:

```
    for (ScanResult scanResult : listeScan) {
    if(sampleposition[position]==0){ 
        change=true;
        while(i < position && change==true){ 
            if(macAdress[i].equals(scanResult.BSSID)){ 
                change = false;
            }
            i++;
        }
        i=0;
        if(change == true && scanResult.level >= -80){ 
            valueSSID[position] = scanResult.level;
            macAdress[position] = scanResult.BSSID;
            sSID[position] = scanResult.SSID;
            if(valueSSID[position]!=0){sampleposition[position]++;}
            break;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(macAdress[position].equals(scanResult.BSSID) && sampleposition[position]<=totalsample){addlevel=scanResult.level;} else {addlevel=0;}
        valueSSID[position] = valueSSID[position] + addlevel;
            if(addlevel!=0){sampleposition[position]++;}
             break;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use keyword

```
break;
```

where you want to stop the loop

```
for (ScanResult scanResult : listeScan) {
if(sampleposition[position]==0){ 
    change=true;
    while(i < position && change==true){ 
        if(macAdress[i].equals(scanResult.BSSID)){ 
            change = false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    if(change == true && scanResult.level >= -80){ 
        valueSSID[position] = scanResult.level;
        macAdress[position] = scanResult.BSSID;
        sSID[position] = scanResult.SSID;
        if(valueSSID[position]!=0){sampleposition[position]++;}
      break;
    }
}
else{
    if(macAdress[position].equals(scanResult.BSSID) && sampleposition[position]<=totalsample){addlevel=scanResult.level;} else {addlevel=0;}
    valueSSID[position] = valueSSID[position] + addlevel;
        if(addlevel!=0){sampleposition[position]++;}
      break;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
break;
```

Please refer to the following links for further information.

1) [Control Flow - Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow)

2) ["Break" and "Continue" in JAVA](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/programs/break/break.html)

Hope they would help.